# Deploying failed when I am trying to deploying applicaion in mule 3.4.2 server

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Deploying failed when I am trying deploying applicaion

The below error I am getting. could you please help me out on this?

```
WARN  2015-06-19 15:02:42,393 [[bmrs_mule_phase2_2.0.12].http.request.dispatch.7051.01] com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase: Failure processing throttling phase null
ERROR 2015-06-19 15:02:42,394 [[bmrs_mule_phase2_2.0.12].http.request.dispatch.7051.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:76)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:1)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidationPhase.runPhase(ValidationPhase.java:36)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidationPhase.runPhase(ValidationPhase.java:15)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:98)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.processMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:550)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver.processRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:59)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpRequestDispatcherWork.run(HttpRequestDispatcherWork.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
WARN  2015-06-19 15:02:42,397 [[bmrs_mule_phase2_2.0.12].http.request.dispatch.7051.01] com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase: Failure processing throttling phase null
ERROR 2015-06-19 15:02:42,397 [[bmrs_mule_phase2_2.0.12].http.request.dispatch.7051.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:76)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:1)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidationPhase.runPhase(ValidationPhase.java:36)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidationPhase.runPhase(ValidationPhase.java:15)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:98)
```

Comment: Can you post your Xml also ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the (decompiled) source code, the issue comes from the fact no `ThrottlingManager` is available to your application, not even the default one which is bound in the registry under key `_muleThrottlingManager` for Mule EE servers.

This is a wild guess but I think you're trying to deploy a Mule application built for Mule `3.4.2 EE` on a `3.4.2 CE` server: you need to deploy on an `EE` server.

Comment: I am deploying the application in EE server.

Comment: I tried deploying application in EE server only.. I found error because I have used blocking="false" property in http reconnection strategy. If I removed that property it is working fine..i.e I am able to deploy it.could u please explain the use of blocking="false" property?

Comment: Sounds like a bug then: since you are an Enterprise customer, I suggest you escalate this to Mulesoft professional support.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to deploy the application to CE runtime. Try deploying to EE Runtime